# How do we create an IndexRequest in Java for ElasticSearch 7.4.2 Java High Level REST Client?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7, resthighlevelclient

I am trying to insert data into ElasticSearch (version 7.4.2) hosted on bonsai.io cloud. When I try to create an IndexRequest & IndexResponse in my client code in Java (Java High Level REST client), there is no import available for both IndexRequest & IndexResponse.

My pom.xml has the following dependencies:

```
  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.4.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
```

I even tried adding the below dependency to my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>7.4.2</version>
  </dependency>
```

Can somebody help me solve this issue in 7.4.2 version?

Comment: Create a [mcve], including code please

Comment: You mentioned kafka, though, so why not use Kafka Connect?

Comment: What do you mean by no import available, can you please share the screen-shot of these jars available in your class-path ?

Comment: I found the error and fixed it. 2 jar files; elasticsearch-7.4.2.jar & elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.4.2.jar weren't accesible. So, I cleared the .m2 local cache and built my pom.xml again and it worked. Thank you @cricket_007 for your input.

Comment: @OpsterESNinja thank you for your input. I was able to fix the error. Reason is mentioned in the above comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error occurred as the maven build was unable to read the jar manifest for following 2 jar files.

1) .m2/repository/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/7.4.2/elasticsearch-7.4.2.jar
2) .m2/repository/org/elasticsearch/client/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client/7.4.2/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.4.2.jar

Solved the error by deleting the .m2 directory locally. Running the pom.xml after this as a maven build fixed the error and the above 2 jars were installed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this](https://github.com/bhavya121999/ServerCode) GitHub repo which is using ES 7.3 with java high-level rest client. You can change the ES client version in pom.xml and ready to go, as these are just minor version change, there isn't really any change in `IndexRequest` and `indexResponse` APIs.

Please see [this](https://github.com/bhavya121999/ServerCode/blob/6ec30453ac1e98b40ae94f65fd79ae7d1c75ec87/src/main/java/com/indore/GalaxyApp.java#L113) of `com.indore.GalaxyApp#createIndex` method, where IndexRequest is created.

You can change your elasticsearch details [config.yml](https://github.com/bhavya121999/ServerCode/blob/master/config.yml) and read the README section on how to start the app.

Let me know if you need more information.